# Posting on Facebook Page with video id

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What are the parameters to post on a Facebook page with an already uploaded video using Graph API. I have the video id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may this is useful for you from facebook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#crosspostedvideos